# linux + how to measure ssh time until login to remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, rhel

we want to measure the time that is needed until ssh successfully login to remote machine

is it possible to measure ssh time until login to remote machine?

note - all machine are RHEL machines

for example

lets say we want to verify how much time is needed to login `machine_X` from `machine_Y`

example from `machine_Y`

while `machine_X is machine_[1..100]`

```
ssh time until login to machine1 was 2 sec
ssh time until login to machine2 was 6 sec
ssh time until login to machine3 was 12 sec
ssh time until login to machine4 was 3 sec
.
.
.
```

Comment: You are doing SSH session in your command prompt?

Comment: As `ssh` can also execute commands after logging in (terminating the session afterwards), you could probably work with something like `time ssh $machine_X true` (with `true` being used as basically no-op remote command).

Comment: `for machine_X in machine_{1..100}; do env time -f "ssh time until login to $machine_X was %e sec" ssh "$machine_X" : 2>/dev/null; done`

Comment: @LéaGris you should post that as answer so it can be up/downvoted, commented on in an attached thread, and/or accepted as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# using bash variable SECONDS 
for srv in machine_{1..100}; do
     START=$SECONDS;        
     ssh "$srv" /usr/bin/true; 
     printf "ssh time until login to %s was %s sec\n" "$srv" "$((SECONDS-START))"; 
done
```

---

```
ssh time until login to machine1 was 1 sec
ssh time until login to machine2 was 0 sec
ssh time until login to machine3 was 0 sec
ssh time until login to ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For each ssh print the date in epoch secs locally, then print the epoch secs remotely, then do a subtraction:

```
user='whatever'
for machine_X in machine_{1..100}; do
    { date +%s; ssh "${user}@${machine_X}" 'date +%s'; } |
    awk -v mc="$machine_X" '
        NR%2 { begSecs=$1; next }
        { printf "ssh time until login to %s was %d sec\n", mc, $1 - begSecs }
    '
done
```

We're doing the second call to `date` remotely so we only consider the time to log IN using ssh and not also the time to log OUT again as would be included if we did both calls to `date` locally.

We're using command grouping to call date and ssh to minimize overhead (and so added irrelevant time) during and between those calls. We are not using process substitution (`time=$(date...)`), for example, as that adds overhead as the shell often will have to create a temp file and write the result of the command to it before assigning it to the variable so then you're adding the time it takes to do that onto the time it took `ssh` log in. That makes the awk code very slightly more complicated than if we used other approaches that would output both timestamps on 1 line but that's a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

If the time on the machines is accurate, and you have a recent version of `GNU date`, this will measure the time difference at nano-second level :

```
#!/bin/bash

for srv in machine_{1..100}; do
    start="$(date +%s.%N)"
    end="$(ssh "$srv" date +%s.%N)"
    diff="$(bc <<< "$end - $start")"
    test "${diff:0:1}" = . && diff="0$diff"
    echo "ssh time until login to $srv was $diff seconds."
done
```

Comment: just one note when its less then 1 second , then we get number as - .410716980 seconds , so 0 is missing , should be for example 0.410716980